# Error during FCM registration. Please set your project ID

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, salesforce-mobile-sdk

I'm building a salesforce android kotlin mobile app and I'm currently implementing the push notifications feature. I have started my project from the forcedroid create template.
I have added all necessary classpath and dependencies in project and app module's build.gradle files.
I have followed these two guides:

[Firebase setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message#kotlin+ktx_1)

[Salesforce Push Notifications Android Setup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/push_android_conn_app.htm)

The error mentioned in the title occurs when starting the main activity of the app after logging in (indeed it does not show when you start the app and you are already logged in).
Since there are way too many files influenced by the changes I'm gonna post the code on demand, unless you want me to write everything here.

**Thank you for your efforts**, hope you can solve this issue, bye!

Comment: The error clearly states you haven't set a project ID (or perhaps it's incorrect). One of the first articles in the Firebase documentation is "Understand Firebase projects" which goes a lot into the project ID. While a quick glance didn't show me where you have to enter the project ID, I'd say check your config files or even do a project-wide search.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs thank you so much for answering. Unfortunately I've already spent 3 days on checking every guide. I tried following them starting from scratch twice, tried searching on the internet, searching in the project, everywhere. The project id is written correctly in google.services.json and gets written correctly in values.xml when compiling. Still it throws that error, I think it's a salesforce-side problem but the documentation doesn't help at all :(

Comment: Then I'd suggest checking/asking the salesforce forums.